# Harmonic functions and geometric mean

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u$ is harmonic in $B_{R}(0)$ and $0<a \le b \le c < R$ ar such that $ac=b^2$. Show that: 
$\int_{|\omega|=1}u(a\omega)u(c\omega)d\omega=\int_{|\omega|=1}(u(b\omega))^2d\omega$

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: I tried to apply mean value property and Cauchy inequality.

Comment: I have posted a hint. Try to work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define $F$ by $$F(x,y)=\int_{|\eta|=1} u(xy\eta)u(x^{-1}y\eta)d\eta$$

where $0<xy<R$ and $0<x^{-1}y<R$. Prove that $F$ does not depends on $x$. One way to prove it is to show that $$\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}=0\tag{1}$$

From $(1)$ we conclude that $F(x,y)=F(x,z)$. Now note that $$F\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}},\sqrt{ac}\right)=\int_{|\eta|=1}u(a\eta)u(c\eta)d\eta\tag{2}$$

$\cdots$